# Prometheus-operator cannot get pod CPU/memory usage

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

I installed Prometheus operator Helm chart on my k8s cluster. I had a look at Grafana and could see the node CPU and memory usage. However Prometheus doesn't manage to collect pod CPU/memory usage.
For instance `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod_name!=""}[5m]))` would return `no data`.
`kubectl top pod` works fine so I cannot understand why Prometheus won't manage to get this data. Or is the rule above wrong perhaps?

I'm using:

- Minikube 1.4.0
- kvm2 driver
- Kubernetes 1.15.4
- Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57961250/10589890

Comment: I'm totally new to Prometheus so I might say something stupid here: isn't what you describe for pulling custom application metrics? What I am trying to achieve is pulling node_exporter or metrics-server. And I assume that Prometheus-operator should be already configured out-of-the box to pull things like CPU/memory usage metrics. Am I wrong?

Comment: thats the regular process. just add the `prometheus.io/scrape: "true" ` annotation, it should work.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work with `prometheus.io/scrape: "true"`. I still don't get any CPU data.

Comment: Hi @stackoverflowed what infrastructure are you running you Minikube on?

Comment: @PiotrMalec I added vm driver and linux version to the question.

Comment: @stackoverflowed, Did you follow helm chart part about [`prometheus.io/scrape`](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#prometheusioscrape) and about using `serviceMonitor`?